# CMake - is there a way to check if testing is enabled?

Tags: testing, cmake

I believe I found a piece of code that did just that, but with the documentation of CMake being so poor, I can't seem to find it anymore.

In short: is there something like:

```
if(testing_enabled)
```

I can use in CMakeLists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you're thinking of the [`BUILD_TESTING`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/module/CTest.html) option which is enabled by doing:

```
include(CTest)
```

and is `ON` by default.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to check the option [CMAKE_TESTING_ENABLED](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmEnableTestingCommand.cxx):

```
if(CMAKE_TESTING_ENABLED)
    do_your_job_here()
endif()
```